# arrays value string edit and loop in combination with other array and looping

Tags: php, arrays

## for each Example 1 caption and some occurrences for the source map

What am I doing wrong?

**Images Array**

```php
$imgsArray = array(
  'image1-small.jpg', 'image1-medium.jpg', 'image1-large.jpg',
  'image2-small.jpg', 'image2-medium.jpg', 'image2-large.jpg',
  'image3-small.jpg', 'image3-medium.jpg', 'image3-large.jpg'
); // sometimes more pictures too
```

**Captions Array**

```php
$imgCaption = array('Adam','Peter'); // if e.g. with 3 pictures only 2 captions are available then I get Notice: Undefined offset:
```

**the code**

```php
foreach($imgsArray as $files => $img) {
  // important! $first_char. delete from hyphen to the last string
  $first_char = substr($img,0,strpos($img,"-"));
  ///
  if ($first_char != $last_entry) {
  echo '<p>This is '.$imgCaption[$files];
  echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-small.jpg</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-medium.jpg</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-large.jpg</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$imgCaption[$files].'</li>';
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '<i>Ciao, '.$imgCaption[$files].'</i><br>---</p>';
  }
  $last_entry = $first_char;
}
```

**unexpected**

This is Adam

- image1-small.jpg
- image1-medium.jpg
- image1-large.jpg
- Adam

*Ciao, Adam*
---

This is *Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...*

- image2-small.jpg
- image2-medium.jpg
- image2-large.jpg
- *Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...*

*Ciao, *Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...*
---*

This is *Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...*

- image3-small.jpg
- image3-medium.jpg
- image3-large.jpg
- *Notice:  Undefined offset: 6 in...*

Ciao, Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...
---

**expected**

This is Adam

- image1-small.jpg
- image1-medium.jpg
- image1-large.jpg
- Adam

Ciao, Adam
---

This is Peter

- image2-small.jpg
- image2-medium.jpg
- image2-large.jpg
- Peter

Ciao, Peter
---

This is

- image3-small.jpg
- image3-medium.jpg
- image3-large.jpg
- Susi

Ciao, 
---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try my below code

```
<?php
$imgsArray = array(
  'image1-small.jpg', 'image1-medium.jpg', 'image1-large.jpg',
  'image2-small.jpg', 'image2-medium.jpg', 'image2-large.jpg',
  'image3-small.jpg', 'image3-medium.jpg', 'image3-large.jpg'
);

$imgCaption = array('Adam','Peter','Susi');

$files = 0;

for( $i= 0; $i < count($imgsArray); $i=$i+3 ){
  if(!isset($imgCaption[$files])) break;
  $first_char = substr($imgsArray[$i],0,strpos($imgsArray[$i],"-"));

  echo '<p>This is '.$imgCaption[$files];
  echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-small.jpg</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-medium.jpg</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-large.jpg</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$imgCaption[$files].'</li>';
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '<i>Ciao, '.$imgCaption[$files].'</i><br>---</p>';

  $files++;
}
```

[Demo link](https://3v4l.org/7uEbs)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, what if the array quantities are not the same? e.g. $ imgCaption = array ('Adam', 'Peter'); Notice: Undefined offset: ...

Comment: One question. your `$imgsArray` sequence will be always correct ? If so I ll alter my answer

Comment: // sometimes more pictures too.

Comment: I think 3 Images each of the 3 captions, Can you please elaborate, Question is bit confusing.. Need to find a combination in your question. I thought if caption is ('Adam', 'Peter'); Then only 6 values might be there in $imgsArray

Comment: Your solution helped me. But if e.g. with 3 pictures only 2 captions are available then I get Notice: Undefined offset

Comment: @CemFirat A checking inside for loop will solve the issue , please check this link  https://3v4l.org/75S4W

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211425/discussion-between-ajith-and-cem-firat).